# XPath: Find node from closest parent

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need the text from the h3 headline closest to the current node. The current node is the td-element of that table. How can I find the text from the closest h3 headline relativly to the current node with XPath?

I've tried:

```
//ancestor-or-self::[@class="uk-panel"]/h3/text()
```

But that doesn't work. I'm really new to XPath though. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You should paste text, formatted as code, not images, into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
preceding::h3[1]
```

will select the immediately preceding `h3` element from the context node.

Then, you can select its children text nodes,

```
preceding::h3[1]/text()
```

or select its string value:

```
string(preceding::h3[1])
```